# How force developers to use constructor without arguments if value supposed to be default?

Tags: java

```
public class Student {
    
    public Student(String name){
        do_smth(name);
    }
    
    public Student(){
        this("Mike");
    }
}
```

How force developers to use parameterized constructor only if value differs from default:
not calling new Student("Mike") but use for this new Student()?

The reason: we have constructor with 5 parameters. In most cases parameters are the same. But there are about 5%-10% cases when they differ.
 So in order to avoid duplications, I would like to use such approach.
I know it maybe better to use smth like Builder pattern here. But I don't like it verbosity.

Comment: Why would you wan that ? If you want to throw an exception if the name argument is set to "Mike" you could just throw the exception after an if statement...

Comment: What would be the point of adding such a constraint?

Comment: This seems a very bad idea as such... either this firstname is important and it should be mandatory in the constructor, either it is not and it should be left empty if not provided in the constructor

Comment: Your question smells of being an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is to use a completely different approach. Better that you tell us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: I also fail to see the point in this context, I would expect more actually if you wanted to set the public Student(String name) as mandatory, since it kind make sense to make the variable name final

Comment: We have constructor with 5 parameters. In most cases parameters are the same. But there are about 5%-10% cases when they differ.
 So in order to avoid duplications, I would like to use such approach.
I know it maybe better to use smth like Builder pattern here. But I don't like it verbosity.

Comment: Good documentation will help developers to use the right constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be implemented by using additional private constructor with a flag:

```java
public class Student {    
    public Student(String name) {
        this(name, false);
    }
    
    public Student() {
        this("Mike", true);
    }

    private Student(String name, boolean defaultUsed) {
        if (!defaultUsed && "Mike".equals(name)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Tut-tut lil kid, it's pwohibited to set Mike's name outside defauwt constwuctor");
        }
        do_smth(name); // only if do_smth cannot be overridden in child classes
    }
}
```

*Note*: method `do_smth` should be `private` or `final` so that it could not be overloaded in subclasses which is far more important than setting a limit on setting a name from specific constructor.

Comment: That is a clever solution, although I'd still much rather that the OP give us the background information for why they are insisting on doing this